# JAVA error: "E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)"

Tags: java, android

I'm having a problem with my radio, the radio works and everything, but the thing is that when I pressed Pause the radio stops, but, when i click on PLAY again, the radio starts again, but like if it where a song. Conclusion (sorry for my bad explanation) 
when  i use OnPause() this happens
weird example===

if I start playing 1:00pm , and then I paused 1:01pm, then  wait a couple minutes, and play again, the radio will continue playing like if it where 1:01pm, and it's 1:05pm (awkward example)

when i changed to OnStop()
 it gave me MediaPlayer code error(-38,0)

```
enter code here :::::: b_play = findViewById(R.id.b_play);
    b_play.setEnabled(false);
    b_play.setText("Cargando...");

    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    new PlayerTask().execute(stream);

    b_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                if (started) {
                    started = false;
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    b_play.setText("Escuchar");

                } else {
                    started = true;
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    b_play.setText("Pausar");
                }

        }




    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(strings[0]);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            prepared = true;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return prepared;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
        mediaPlayer.start();
        b_play.setEnabled(true);
        b_play.setText("Escuchar");


    }

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onStop();
    if (started) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (started) {
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (prepared) {
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }

}
```

If u could help me out, i'll do apprecciate, I'm sorry about my english and weird explanation (?

Answer (score 0):

remove onPause with onStop

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (started) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (started) {
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (prepared) {
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }

}
```

Comment: may it will help you

Comment: Sorry, i wrote wrongly , Writting OnStop(){} , it happens that i stopped the radio, and when i play again, it gave me error (-38.0)

Comment: which line of code being called when you play again